# Inner Join on 2 tables having multiple join value

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have the following tables where a few of the columns are included here:

```
Table 1:
Id RefId PhoneNumber 
1  11    919191
2  11    888888
3  11    919191

Table 2:
Id RefId City    UniqueId
1  11    Mumbai  111
2  11    Pune    222
3  11    Nashik  333
```

I want a few columns from `Table1` and `Table2`. Common in both table is `RefId`. `Table2` has `UniqueId` which is primary key of `Table2`. If I do an inner join based on `RefId` I will get 9 records, but I want 3. How do I get that?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT T1.PhoneNumber,T2.City,T2.UniqueId,T2.RefId
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.RefId = T2.RefId
```

Comment: Tag your question and show the results you want.  How do you intend to match the rows?

Comment: what about the `id` is it unique? Try `SELECT * FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id`

Comment: if UniqueId is the primary key of table2 then what is ID and why have you got it in that table? Surely it's redundant?

Comment: Anyway, which SQL DBMS is it? SQL Server? MySQL? Please tag it appropriately, sometimes it can affect how the query can be written. Secondly, you say RefId is the common field, but it doesn't look like it can be the relationship, because it is duplicated in table1, so it's not the primary key. Therefore if you do a join on these fields it'll match every row with 11 in table1 with every row with 11 in table2, hence the 9 records. I think you need to check your table relationships and keys again. perhaps in fact "id" in table2 is the foreign key to "id" in table1?

Comment: How do you make the relation between Table 1 and Table 2?

Comment: Which 3 would you want?

Answer (score 0):

If the ID is used to join as well then

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.RefId, t1.PhoneNumber, t2.City, t2.UniqueId
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
AND t1.RefId = t2.RefId
```

If the Ids are randomly generated them you probably shouldn't join on them.

If the Ids were random but all of the PhoneNumbers were for the same place then you could just pick the Minimum value PhoneNumber (or Max)

```
SELECT t2.RefId, t1.PhoneNumber, t2.City, t2.UniqueId
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT RefId, MIN(PhoneNumber) AS PhoneNumber
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY RefId
    ) t1 ON t1.RefId = t2.RefId
```